# Monotonicity of this series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Given the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=e^{x-1}$ we have the series $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ where:

$x_1=2$ and $x_{n+1}=f(x_n), n\ge1$

Find the monotonicity of the series and compute $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(x_n\right)$

I think the function is strictly increasing, but I'm not sure if I worked correctly...

Comment: Monotonicity, not monotony

Comment: How did you decide that the sequence (not series) was increasing?

Comment: Well I computed $x_1, x_2,x_3$ and I found somewhat of a pattern where $x_n=e^{e^{n-3}\left(e-1\right)}$ and since $e>2$ and $e-1 \gt 1$ it should be an increasing sequence since the powers keep increasing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** to establish that the sequence is increasing, it suffices to show that $f(x) > x$ for all $x \geq 2$.

One way to do so is to check that $f(2) > 2$, then notice that the function $f(x) - x$ has a positive derivative.

Comment: I showed that $f(x) > x$ for $x\ge2$, I used the derivative though. Ok, so the function is increasing, does that mean that the limit I have to compute is $+\infty$?

Comment: That, by itself, is not enough to prove that the limit is $\infty$.  However, the fact that $f(x) - x$ is increasing (in particular, we don't have [$f(x) - x] \to 0$) is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to show that $f(x_n)>x_n$, or
$$
e^{x-1} > x
$$
for $x\ge 2$. Let $x=1+y$; then
$$
e^y > 1 + y,
$$
which is well-known inequality for $y > 0$.

And now about limit. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists and equals to $a$. By condition,
$$
x_{n+1}=e^{x_n-1} \Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{x_n-1} \Longrightarrow a = e^{a-1}
$$
(we used continuity of exp). However, this equation have single root $a=1$, which is not a limit obviously. So, $x_n$ stricly increasing and unbound (if it's bounded, then limit exists); hence it tends to infinity.

Comment: Does that mean that the sequence is strictly increasing and the limit is equal to $+\infty$?

Comment: @MikhaelM, it's strictly increasing, yes. But it can be bound (or cannot). $-1/n$ is strictly increasing, but have a finite limit.

Comment: Well I guess my sequence is bounded below but not bounded above? Wouldn't that mean that the limit when $x\to\infty$ is $\infty$?